# Python Class inside Class using same methods

Tags: python, class, methods

If I writing a class inside a class, and them both use same methods i.e.:

```
class Master:  
  def calculate(self):  
    variable = 5
    return variable
  class Child:
    def calculate(self):
      variable = 5
      return variable
```

Do I have to declare this method in both classes, or can I only declare it in the Master, and then use it in Child?

Comment: *Why* are you nesting your classes? The classes have no relationship other than that `Child` becomes an attribute on `Master`; methods are *not* shared.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Those classes have completely different fields, but use one or two same methods. Maybe it's not quite a good code, but an answer will be accepted greatfully.

Comment: Then why not use inheritance? Put methods that are to be shared on a base class instead.

Comment: I really want the Child to be a field of Master. Is there better method to do it? I using it in django, I want to use this relationship later to see the Child instances inside of Master fields in html.

Comment: You can always give `Master` a `child` attribute and assign a `Child` instance to that. Then each `Master` **instance** has a `Child` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesting one class inside another has no other effect than that the nested class becomes an attribute on the outer class. They have no other relationship.

In other words, `Child` is a class that can be addressed as `Master.Child` instead of just plain `Child`. Instances of `Master` can address `self.Child`, which is a reference to the same class. And that's where the relationship ends.

If you wanted to share methods between two classes, use inheritance:

```
class SharedMethods:
    def calculate(self):  
        variable = 5
        return variable

class Master(SharedMethods):
    pass

class Child(SharedMethods):
    pass
```

Here both `Master` and `Child` now have a `calculate` method.

Since Python supports multiple inheritance, creating a mixin class like this to share methods is relatively painless and doesn't preclude using other classes to denote is-a relationships.

Leave containment relationships to instances; give your `Master` a `child` attribute and set that to a `Child` instance.

Comment: Thank you. If my code file will contain about 20 classes, where some of them will have same methods with 1 another class. Will it make the code unreadable, as there will be about 5 classes of shared methods for different classes? (not in my case, but interesting...)

Comment: @Alexander: If you have that many different classes with *some* shared methods, you need to perhaps rethink your architecture. :-)