# python 2.7: creating method at runtime using locals as arguments

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, methods, factory

My example uses QT, but is certainly useful in other contexts as well.

In the following example, the create function of the Export class create some function during run-time, passing as arguments local variables. The functions are then called when buttons on the QT GUI are pressed:

```
try:
    from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *      
except : raise Exception("failed to import QT. Is it installed ?")
import time,copy

class Export(QTableWidget):

    class Field:

        def __init__(self,name):
            self.name = name

    def __init__(self):
        self.fields = []

    def add(self,name):
        self.fields.append(self.Field(name))

    def create(self,export_function):

        QTableWidget.__init__(self,len(self.fields),3)

        for index,field in enumerate(self.fields):

            self.setItem(index,0,QTableWidgetItem(field.name))
            editable_widget = QTableWidgetItem("0")
            self.setItem(index,1,QTableWidgetItem(editable_widget))

            print "creating export function: ",field.name,editable_widget

            def export(field_name=field.name,widget=editable_widget):
                print "export ",field_name,widget
                value = widget.text()
                export_function(field_name,value)

            export_button = QtGui.QPushButton('set', self)
            export_button.clicked.connect(export)
            self.setCellWidget(index,2,export_button)

class Export_Qt(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        main_widget = QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(main_widget)
        export = Export()
        export.add("A")
        export.add("B")
        def export_function(field,value): print field,":",value
        export.create(export_function)
        layout.addWidget(export)
        main_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)        
        self.resize(500,350)


if __name__ == '__main__' :

    app = QApplication([]) 
    main_window = Export_Qt(parent=None)
    main_window.show()
    try:
        while True:
            main_window.update()
            QApplication.processEvents()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    except KeyboardInterrupt: pass
    except Exception as e : print e
```

What surprises me is that things half work. The GUI is displayed, and the console prints:

```
creating export function:  A <PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x7fef87c9e9e0>
creating export function:  B <PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x7fef87c9ec20>
```

Then if I push the button corresponding to "B", the console prints:

```
export  False <PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x7fef87c9ec20>
False : 0
```

So, it print "False" were I was expecting "B". But please note that the address of the QTableWidgetItem is correct, so the approach seems to make sense.

Solutions with rapid fix would be great, but I would be super happy if the answer also provide some insight on how python work

note: I know having a class field with only one name attribute does not make sense. This is because the code above a simplification of the real code I am using. For readability.

Comment: Why are you using nested classes? Do you really need that? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22582056/3079302) may give you some explanation about that.

Comment: @iled I like to use nested class to hide internals to end users (including future myself). By exposing Export only, I give myself the freedom to modify Field the way I want. This being said, I should have called the class _Field for clarity on that point.

Comment: You can achieve that with inheritance as well. I'd say it would improve its readability and maintainability. In general, your code is hard to read. Avoid long lines (79 chars max) and use more white space. [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) gives you the guidelines. It is also important to consider that posting code here that is hard to read will scare away readers (and answers). Anyway, nice that you solved it by yourself and posted the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
class Export(QTableWidget):

    class Field:

        def __init__(self,name):
            self.name = name

    def __init__(self):
        self.fields = []
        self.editable_widgets = []

    def add(self,name):
        self.fields.append(self.Field(name))

    def _create(self,field_index,export_function):
        self.setItem(field_index,0,QTableWidgetItem(self.fields[field_index].name))
        editable_widget = QTableWidgetItem("pouet")
        self.editable_widgets.append(editable_widget)
        self.setItem(field_index,1,editable_widget)

        print "creating export function: ",self.fields[field_index].name,editable_widget,editable_widget.text()

        def export():
            print "export ",field_index,self.fields[field_index].name,self.editable_widgets[field_index]
            export_function(self.fields[field_index].name,self.editable_widgets[field_index].text())

        export_button = QtGui.QPushButton('set', self)
        export_button.clicked.connect(export)
        self.setCellWidget(field_index,2,export_button)


    def create(self,export_function):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self,len(self.fields),3)
        for index in range(len(self.fields)):
               self._create(index,export_function)
```

This makes sense. After leaving the create function, field is not a valid address anymore. So field_name = field.name does not make sense.
On the other end, the widget is still around (managed somewhere in QT), so things work for it.

In the solution above, I make sure I point to something that still exists once create is left.